# proof of that we can find a sentence σ s.t. σ is true in theory A but not deducible from A

Tags: number-theory, logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, predicate-logic

I read the book of titled "a mathematical introduction to logic" written by Enderton at pp.184-185.

i don't understand thm 30A's proof procedure. i understand proof's way intended that constructs some formula σ that it says itself can't be deduced from A.
but i understand next procedure about def of relation R in proof :
" ... and c is the value of G at some deduction from of α(S^b0)"
(because the book says G means Godel number of deduction but i can't understand α(S^b0)'s means")

so then i can't understand what the proof say except proof's intention.

so i want to know what does R means and how a given proof procedure solves the theorem, i.e. why formula σ can be expressed that σ does not have deduction from A.

[image]

[image]

[image]